# Typescript extend any type

Tags: typescript

Ive googled and tried a lot and cannot find something.

Is there a way to extend "any" object in typescript like
in c# where i can write a extension method for the "object"
type.

It would make it possible to implement e.g. a `cast<T>` method which casts any object to the typescript type `T`.

e.g. i can do...

```
declare global {
    interface Array {
       doSomething();
    }
}

Array.prototype.doSomething = function() {
    console.log(this);
};
```

but i cant

```
declare global {
    interface any {
       doSomething();
    }
}

any.prototype.doSomething = function() {
    console.log(this);
};
```

I know that this is not possible but maybe there is a workaround
or trick i can use to extend "any" or "{}" or...

Comment: I don't think that's possible in javascript thus not possible in ts either.

Comment: `any`  and `{}` are not the same. `any` also contains primitive values, whereas `{}` is an `Objects`. If you only need this extension for `Objects`, your approach might work.

Comment: @HerrDerb thats right. I think i can archive what i want by extending Object. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`any` and `{}` are not the same. `any` be a primitive value or an `Object`, whereas `{}` is an Object. If you only need this extension for objects, your could extend `Object`.